# How to Scroll input into view but with some margin on top

Tags: javascript, css

Check the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/g2djbwm5/1/

1. Scroll the page untill the input is visible.
2. Type in something but keep the focus into it
3. Using the mouse scroll the page again until the input is no longer visible
4. Now type in something
   Input will be scrolled into view to the very top like this
   [image]

Is there any way to show this input not very top but some 20px from the top when user type in? something like

[image]

Code:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">..............</div>
<input type="text"/>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can use this to make the scroll stops some px above:

```
scroll-margin-top: 50px;
```

an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top)

Answer (score 0):

This decision comes to my mind, but this solution is a `"crutch" (hack)`.

The problem with this solution is that when scrolling, the input loses its sticky positioning and returns its default coordinates.

If my small solution is modified, taking into account the preservation of the position of the input when scrolling, then the solution will be good, as it seems to me.

```js
let input_text = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

input_text.oninput = function() {
  this.classList.add('top_for_input');
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  input_text.classList.remove('top_for_input');
}
```

```css
.top_for_input {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">..............</div>
<input type="text"/>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to locate the y position of the element -> input. Then an event listener  for `input` and conditional to check the position of the element. If it is off the page when focused and the event is `input`, place it on top and change the position to sticky else position relative.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let inputPos = -1;
if (input === document.activeElement) {
  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (inputPos < 0) inputPos = findPosY(input);

    if (pageYOffset > inputPos) {
      input.style.cssText = 'position:sticky; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;';
    } else {
      input.style.position = 'relative;';
    }
  });
}


function findPosY(obj) {
  let curtop = 0;
  if (typeof(obj.offsetParent) != 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent) {
    while (obj.offsetParent) {
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
  } else if (obj.y)
    curtop += obj.y;
  return curtop;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 800px;">..............</div>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<div class="input" style="width: 100%; height: 1800px;" />
```